# Organize photos into folders and access them cross-platform, including mobile

Tags: android, file-management, photography

I have a few thousand photos I've taken over the course of years, organized neatly into folders. I've avoided using "albums" or other organizational features of any proprietary software (like Apple Photos) that would lock me in to their way of doing things. I do often use Picasa to browse and tag my photos (The tags are stored in EXIF metadata, not in a proprietary database) and I currently keep them in Dropbox for access on any device. This gives me access to my organized photos on any Mac, PC, or Windows system, regardless of installed software.

However, the Dropbox app for Android is just awful for photo viewing. When you open its photo browsing mode, it ignores your folder structure completely, and shows you a stream of all your photos, organized by date. On the other hand, if you browse to a folder full of images, it shows them in the generic "file list" view with minuscule thumbnails and only a few items per page, clearly not optimized for photo viewing.

- Is there any way I can keep my photos synced to my Android phone, and browse them through the folders I have organized them into?
- Is there any Android app that will let me sort/filter/search these images according to their tags?
- Since space is limited on my Android device, as is the screen resolution, is there any way I can sync lower-res images to my phone for rapid, off-line access - again, maintaining my folder structure - while keeping the high-res images on my computer or a cloud service?

Comment: google drive or google photos?  picasa will even sync them for you.  You can uncheck the original size box and give you a downsized version.

Answer (score 2):

Since android has only native exif-support but no native IPTC-tag-support and there are no iptc-capable software libraries yet there are no open-standard apps that support tags on android (as far as i know of)

My current solution to the same problem

- The photo collection is on a pc in folders below /user/mydata/myphotos/myPhotoRoot
- i use pc-software-irfanview to create a downscaled copy of the images that are copied to my android device
- on the android side i use [APhotoManager](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager) where i am the author of.

Currently [under development](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/issues/25):

- pc

  - batch program that collects tag-data from images into a csv file for android
- android

  - load the tag-csv-data into media database
  - find photos by tags
  - edit photo-tags
  - create a batch that thransfert the tag-changes back to pc

For more details see https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki/sync

[Update 2017-05-07]

I just released APhotoManager-v0.6.0.170502 on fdroid that also supports tags/image-title/image-description via seperate xmp sidecarfiles.

The next version 0.6.1 will also allow to write tags/image-title/image-description to exif